# Is there a maximum number of windows?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

Is there a maximum number of windows that an application can have in iOS?

I mean, if I want to design an application and I want to use 100 different windows, can I do that?

I just want to know if the system allows it, not if it's not an intelligent way to work.

Comment: Do you mean multiple `UIWindows`? Or do you just mean multiple "screens" / "pages" / etc?

Comment: Try it. What happens?

Comment: Hi I mean UIWindows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to use 100 different windows, nothing will stop you. And as I think you suspect, that would be a horrible design. Creating a custom `UIWindow` is only for very specialized kinds of problems. In a decade of iOS development, I think I've created about three of them.